# BootstrapVue table-template inside Vue slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I want to create a parent component for a bootstrap-vue table with custom data rendering (templates).

Right now, this kinda looks like this:

```
<b-table
     :items="result"
     :fields="fields"
     :current-page="currentPage"
     :per-page="perPage">
    <template slot="Index" slot-scope="data">
        {{ data.index + 1 }}
    </template>
    <!-- more templates for various columns here -->
</b-table>
<b-pagination 
     align="center" 
     :total-rows="result.length" 
     v-model="currentPage" 
     :per-page="perPage"
/>
```

The reason I want to wrap this in a component is because I use this table layout, including the pagination and all of its attributes (like striped, bordered, etc.) multiple times.

The only thing that changes, are the column-templates.

I know, the Vue way to do that would be to create a slot like `<slot name="x"></slot>` and fill it with `<template slot="x">...</template>`. For one thing, that would coincide with the bootstrap-vue `template` and on the other hand, bootstrap-vue only seems to render the templates correctly, if they are placed right inside `b-table`.

Basically, what I want to achieve is a component like this:

```
<b-table>
    <slot name="templates"/>
</b-table>
<b-pagination stuff.../>
```

And use it in a child component like this:

```
<TemplateTable>
    <template slot="templates">
        <template slot="Index" slot-scope="data">
            {{ data.index + 1 }}
        </template>
        <!-- more templates -->
    </template>
</TableTemplate>
```

Has anyone done something like this and figured out a way to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

just build your custom component and pass any custom props you need some thing like this:

```
<template>
  <b-table v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" custom-prop="any">
    <slot v-for="(_, name) in $slots" :name="name" :slot="name" />
    <template
      v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots"
      :slot="name"
      slot-scope="slotData"
      ><slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData"
    /></template>
  </b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AppTable',
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

this works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

[You can use a component's render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Slots) to pass slots and scopedSlots to another component (like `b-table`). But then you don't get to use a template. To let you have a template (with pagination, searching, etc.) you can wrap the rendering component into another component that *does* have a template. So then you would have a `custom-table` component which contains pagination and a `table-wrapper` component, and the `table-wrapper` component would render a `b-table`.

Here's a very specific example..

```js
const constItems = [{
    index: 0,
    isActive: true,
    age: 40,
    first_name: 'Dickerson',
    last_name: 'Macdonald'
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    isActive: false,
    age: 21,
    first_name: 'Larsen',
    last_name: 'Shaw'
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    isActive: false,
    age: 89,
    first_name: 'Geneva',
    last_name: 'Wilson'
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    isActive: true,
    age: 38,
    first_name: 'Jami',
    last_name: 'Carney'
  }
];

const bTableProps = {
  items: {
    type: [Array, Function],
    default: undefined
  },
  fields: {
    type: [Object, Array],
    default: undefined
  }
};

const constFields = [
  'index',
  'isActive',
  'age',
  'first_name',
  'last_name'
];

Vue.component('table-wrapper', {
  props: Object.assign({}, bTableProps),
  render(h) {
    return h('b-table', {
      props: this.$props,
      slots: this.$parent.$slots,
      scopedSlots: this.$parent.$scopedSlots,
      on: {
        'row-clicked': (item, index, event) => alert('clicked ' + index)
      }
    });
  }
});

Vue.component('custom-table', {
  template: '<div><h3>hello table</h3><table-wrapper :items="items" :fields="fields"></table-wrapper></div>',
  props: Object.assign({}, bTableProps)
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: constItems,
    fields: constFields
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@6.26.0/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template slot="index" slot-scope="data">
            {{ data.index + 1 }}
        </template>
  </custom-table>
  <custom-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template slot="index" slot-scope="data">
            {{ data.index + 2 }}
        </template>
  </custom-table>
  <custom-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template slot="index" slot-scope="data">
            {{ data.index + 3 }}
        </template>
  </custom-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! It had me in a complete bind trying to figure it out. I'll post my `.vue` solution as well for future reference :)

Comment: Glad it could help. I posted it as much for my own future reference as for everyone else =)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nardnob, this is what I'm using in my `.vue` components. All the `b-table` components have already been loaded in my `app.js` file. Hence the lack of import statements.

First the `TableWrapper.vue`. I've added `Object.assign(this.$attrs, this.$props)` to make sure that any undefined `props` from `CustomTable` will still carry over to `b-table` by combining the `$attrs` and `$props`.

```
<script>
    export default {
        components: {},

        props: [
          'items',
          'fields'
        ],

        mixins: [],

        data: function () {
            return {
                //
            }
        },

        render(h) {
            return h('b-table', {
                props: Object.assign(this.$attrs, this.$props),
                slots: this.$parent.$slots,
                scopedSlots: this.$parent.$scopedSlots,
                on: {
                    // 'row-clicked': (item, index, event) => alert('clicked ' + index)
                }
            });
        },

        computed: {
            //
        },

        created() {
            //
        },

        mounted() {
            //
        },

        methods: {
            //
        },

        watch: {
            //
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then the `CustomTable.vue`:

```
<template>
    <table-wrapper
            :items="items"
            :fields="fields"
            :striped="true"
    ></table-wrapper>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {},

        props: [
          'fields',
          'items',
        ],

        mixins: [],

        data: function () {
            return {
                //
            }
        },

        computed: {
            //
        },

        created() {
            //
        },

        mounted() {
            //
        },

        methods: {
            //
        },

        watch: {
            //
        }
    }
</script>
```

And finally:

```
<custom-table
    :fields="[
        {
            key: 'code',
            label: 'Code',
        },
        {
            key: 'title',
            label: 'Titel',
        },
        {
            key: 'start_date',
            label: 'Start',
        },
        {
            key: 'end_date',
            label: 'End',
        },
        {
            key: 'log',
            label: 'Log'
        }
    ]"
    :items="episodes"
>
    <template v-slot:cell(log)="data">
        <i class="fa-icon fa-search ml-1 is-hoverable" @click="test"></i>
    </template>

</custom-table>
```